# Как сериализовать такой объект?

Tags: java, android, json, serialize, realm

```
{    
"datetimes": [
 {
  "date": "2016-12-14",
  "start_time": "08:00:00",
  "end_time": "22:00:25"
 },
 {
  "date": "2016-12-15",
  "start_time": "08:00:00",
  "end_time": "22:00:25"
 },
 ...
]
}
```

**Дополнение к вопросу:**

```
public class UserDateDeserializer implements JsonSerializer<Date> {

    @Override
public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {

    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject().getAsJsonObject("datetimes");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    JsonArray jsonArray = obj.getAsJsonArray();
    jsonArray.add(new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(src)));


    return obj;
}
}
```

**Класс Event, который наследуется от RealmObject**

```
private RealmList<EventDateTimes> datetimes;
```

**Класс EventDateTimes:**

```
public class EventDateTimes extends RealmObject {


private Date date;

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

P.S. пока что мне нужно понять, как можно сериализовать поле date. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Этот объект уже сериализован. :) Поясните вопрос, пожалуйста. Вас интересует, как написать код, который будет объекты вот такой структуры превращать вот в такой JSON? Или как создать объекты, которые смогут хранить эти данные? Или еще что-то?

Comment: @tse Да, мне нужно написать код, который будет объект превращать вот в такой Json. Я не много запутался.

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, вы сами ответили на свой вопрос - вам нужно написать код. Как именно вы это собираетесь делать - зависит от вас: можете использовать сторонние библиотеки(Jackson), можете написать все самостоятельно.

Comment: @0xFFh я всё равно не понял как правильно сериализовать это :(

Comment: @0xFFh обновил вопрос. Не понимаю в чём ошибка.

Comment: @tse не подскажете в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: ошибка-то в чем? иксепшен, или результат не тот, что ожидался?

Comment: @tse результат не тот, что ожидается. Я не могу сформировать данный Json правильно. Чтоб отправить Json Array в котором объекты.

Comment: тогда классы, которые вы сериализуете, покажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @tse обновил вопрос. Gson, я ещё не использовал, но мне нужно как-то моим способом сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть необходимость создавать JSON вручную, то это можно сделать с помощью стандартных классов JSONObject и JSONArray:

```
    try {
        JSONObject date1 = new JSONObject();
        date1.put("date", "2016-12-14");
        date1.put("start_time", "08:00:00");
        date1.put("end_time", "22:00:25");

        JSONObject date2 = new JSONObject();
        date2.put("date", "2016-12-15");
        date2.put("start_time", "08:00:00");
        date2.put("end_time", "22:00:25");

        JSONArray dates = new JSONArray();
        dates.put(date1);
        dates.put(date2);

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        result.put("datetimes", dates);

        Log.d("happy", result.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Я для сериализации исторически использую библиотеку [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). `obj` из примера ниже может быть любым объектом, сериализатор создаст поля в JSON в соответствии с полями сериализуемого класса. Каждый объект в полях класса тоже будет аналогичным образом сериализован.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Подключается:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

Документация здесь:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема не в сериализаторе, а в описании данных в классах, то можно воспользоваться специальным сервисом. Например, ниже то, что генерит http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ на основе приведенного вами примера.

Заметьте, что в классах расставлены аннотации для сериализатора, его можно выбрать в настройках.

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Datetime.java----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Datetime {

@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
public String date;
@SerializedName("start_time")
@Expose
public String startTime;
@SerializedName("end_time")
@Expose
public String endTime;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("datetimes")
@Expose
public List<Datetime> datetimes = null;

}
```